# Textbox as a wildcard search to populate another textbox using SQL Server Linked table in MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I will try to explain in as much detail as possible.

I have an MS Access form for entering data. Some of the fields on the form are combo boxes from Linked Tables in SQL server.

I want to let the user type in an 8 digit number which then runs a query in the background to display a certain type of value in a DIFFERENT text field. The 8 digit number can have one or more combinations that map to a value.

For example, all of the below numbers pertain to a particular type of value that should be looked up in the SECOND textbox when any of these are entered:

78538973
81004495
82308883
82308892

Whereas, these numbers map to another type of value that should be looked up in second textbox

51692496
53092638
55802678

The easiest way I can think to do this is to create a 'mapping' table with all number combinations that map to each type... Then use an event on the textbox that runs a SQL query against that mapping table and returns the value that should be looked up based on the number.

1. Would that work?
2. Is there an easier/better way to achieve this?
3. Could someone point me in the right direction for VBA code to do this?

Currently the second textbox is just a combobox with a row source query:

```
SELECT code, mascode_desc
FROM XXXXX
ORDER BY code, mascode_desc;
```

Thanks.

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question since it's unclear what the relationship is between different "types" of input number and the query you'd need to run for each of the types.  In general though, using a mapping table seems fine.

Comment: Tim, thanks for the quick response. Put simply, these 8 digits numbers map to types of musical instruments. So for example, some would map to Violin. Some would map to Trumpet. Some would map to Clarinet etc. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes - a mapping table sounds fine, but it's difficult to say anything else without knowing anything about how your database is structured.

Comment: The code you posted, use `WHERE` clause to get mapped values. Then In TextBox after_update event write code `MyComboBox1.Requery` to update result to comboboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post the solution for those looking to achieve the same.

Instead of using a local access or linked SQL mapping table, I was able to use three linked tables in MS Access from a BI data warehouse on SQL server.

I built a query string to join the tables together and return the product information that matches the value the user types into a text box search field.

The results are then returned in a list box with six columns and filtered down based on user input. So for example, if I typed in 7582, list box would display only the records and products that match 7852. If I enter no value into the text field, it will return all product information. I used a 'find' button to achieve this, but the same could be achieved using OnChange or AfterUpdate events... But my users would prefer a button to click.

User can click on selected item, hit upload button, record detail plus some other fields are then uploaded back to SQL server into a different table (there is a logic and reason for doing this) ready to be added to another table elsewhere

Thanks.